# What is the recommended way to Normalize data to a NN (or CNN)?

Tags: neural-networks, data-transformation, dataset, conv-neural-network, normalization

I've seen several ways to normalize a data (features or even images) before use as input in a NN or CNN.

The most common I saw are:

- **[0, 1]**: (data - min(data)) / (max(data) - min(data))
- **z-score**: (data - mean(data)) / std.dev(data)

What would be the best/recommend? Are the way chosen really affect the training of the model?

Please, I'm really lost with so much opinions on this topic, would be good you could provide a reference as paper or book.

Comment: [Should I normalize word2vec's word vectors before using them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/177905/12359)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deep Learning with Python by Francois Chollet](http://www.deeplearningitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Dropbox_Chollet.pdf) (creator of Keras) says to use z-score normalization.

Comment: I thought I'd add this link here to supplement the answer because I didn't know this:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318170/min-max-scaling-on-z-score-standardizd-data
doing min-max scaling is the equivalent of doing z-score norm and then min-max! With all things deep learning, it is helpful to have your data in the same range so both methods don't make a difference but I stick to min-max now because training  sometimes converges faster

Answer (score 3):

There is no best way. If your data was uniformly distributed, you'd probably be better off with scaling by range; for bell shaped distribution the standard deviation based normalization may work better. In the end it rarely matters.

Comment: thank you! do you have any reference on this? any book or paper that support this information?

Comment: AFAIK min-max scaling is more likely to be affected by outliers than standardization.